# How to add a billing label onto a VM from a Go Cloud function?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I want to be able to the equivalent of: `gcloud compute instances add-labels --zone asia-east1-c foobar --labels=hostname=foobar` from a **go113 Cloud function** given a trigger via `protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.instances.insert"`.

I can see there is an API here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setLabels, but I would expect some sort of SDK to make this easier, especially since I am not quite sure how the Oauth works, so I am hoping to find a simple example where this is taken care of.

Comment: [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903961/how-can-i-change-a-vm-instance-label-with-gcp-cloud-function-using-node-js) this post in Stackoverflow, it may help you.

Comment: I *think* it might be https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1#InstancesService.SetLabels but I am not sure

Comment: You're right it's the method setLabels, like in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57919758/8791788) I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the correct IAM permissions to the service account used by your cloud function.
Google Cloud function will use the service account and permission attached to it.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam

Reference on setting Labels on  Google Compute Engine in `go` language - https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1#InstancesService.SetLabels

Terraform is written in `go` language and I find its source code helpful for `golang` example interacting with GCP. For example, https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/google/resource_compute_instance.go#L1039

Comment: But what is the convenience function call to actually add a label?

Comment: How does this answer the question of a Go function to add a billing label?

Comment: The question is around oAuth and service account would make authentication seamless

Comment: it's more than that, I am looking for the convenience function to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setLabels

Comment: Hi Henry - This documentation has details and example about setting labels on Compute Instance - https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1#InstancesService.SetLabels. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the  method id `compute.instances.setLabels` in go [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/master/compute/v1/compute-gen.go) :

```
type InstancesSetLabelsCall struct {
    s                         *Service
    project                   string
    zone                      string
    instance                  string
    instancessetlabelsrequest *InstancesSetLabelsRequest
    urlParams_                gensupport.URLParams
    ctx_                      context.Context
    header_                   http.Header
}

// SetLabels: Sets labels on an instance. To learn more about labels,
// read the Labeling Resources documentation.
func (r *InstancesService) SetLabels(project string, zone string, instance string, instancessetlabelsrequest *InstancesSetLabelsRequest) *InstancesSetLabelsCall {
    c := &InstancesSetLabelsCall{s: r.s, urlParams_: make(gensupport.URLParams)}
    c.project = project
    c.zone = zone
    c.instance = instance
    c.instancessetlabelsrequest = instancessetlabelsrequest
    return c
}
```

You can find a simple example [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/master/examples/compute.go)

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was having a tough time was that I was missing **LabelFingerprint** in the [compute.InstancesSetLabelsRequest](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setLabels) call. Documentation isn't clear that it's required and no error is thrown since I believe the operation is an asynchronous operation.

```
s := strings.Split(instanceEvent.ProtoPayload.ResourceName, "/")
project, zone, instance := s[1], s[3], s[5]
log.Printf("Split %s, to project: %s, zone: %s, instance: %s",
    s,
    project,
    zone,
    instance)

inst, err := computeService.Instances.Get(project, zone, instance).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

existingLabels := inst.Labels
if existingLabels == nil {
    existingLabels = make(map[string]string)
}
existingLabels["hostname"] = instance

log.Println("Applying labels:", existingLabels)

rb := &compute.InstancesSetLabelsRequest{
    LabelFingerprint: inst.LabelFingerprint,
    Labels:           existingLabels,
}
```